# how to use airflow worker to interact other container?

Tags: docker, airflow

As I am install airflow in docker, but it's not possible to execute a operator from worker, to another container, how to solve the issue as

"Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/airflow_test_pycaret/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.